# Is there really moon rock in this cathedral window? If so, how, and from where on the Moon?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-art, sample-return

This  [Tweet](https://twitter.com/IanPineapple/status/1072650637647716354) by NASA Space Flight Editor Ian Atkinson says:

> Some pictures from the Cathedral before the event starts, they have a table set up with artifacts from Apollo 8, including the *flown* flight plan!
>
> There's also a window dedicated to Space exploration, with a moon rock in the glass (inside the white circle near the top).

Is this just space lore, or is there really "*a moon rock*" in the glass? If there is, how did it travel from the Moon to the window, and if known, from where on the moon is it from?

[image: Ian Atkinson Cathederal Moon Rock Window]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the "Space Window" of the National Cathedral in Washington.

[image: Space Window]
Source: [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/topics/history/features/spacewindow.html)

The [National Cathedral website](https://cathedral.org/cathedral-age/the-space-window/) identifies the rock as `Piece 230 of Apollo 11 rock no. 10057`, and further states that it was given by Neil Armstrong, Buzz Aldrin, and Michael Collins on the 5 year anniversary of the first steps on the moon during Apollo 11.

[This NASA page](https://www.nasa.gov/topics/history/features/spacewindowhistory.html) describes the rock and how it was mounted for display:

> In preparation for mounting the 3.6 billion-year-old sample collected by Armstrong and Aldrin, workers sealed a rock section two-and-one-half inches in diameter sealed between two pieces of tempered glass circled with a band of stainless steel. The sealing was done in a nitrogen environment so that any void between the pieces of glass would be filled with nitrogen rather than air, preventing deterioration. The moon rock is a basalt, probably from a lava flow. The mineral pyroxferroite, unknown on Earth, was also discovered in the rock.

Comment: The photos at the NASA page are great, and it looks like there are some interesting diagrams on the window as well. Great sources, thanks!